# Merging two tensors with channel norm

Tags: python, for-loop, pytorch

I want to merge 3-D tensors with channel norm.

My approach is as below :

```
B, C, H, W = x.size()
z = torch.zeros_like(x)

x_norm = torch.norm(x, dim=(2,3))
y_norm = torch.norm(y, dim=(2,3))

for b in range(B):
    for c in range(C): 
        if x_norm[b,c] >= y_norm[b,c]:
            z[b,c] = x[b,c]
        else:
            z[b,c] = y[b,c]
```

But this method is too slow because of uses the two for loop ...

How can I modify the code to process faster?

Comment: If this were numpy, you could say `z = x` and `z[y_norm > x_norm] = y[y_norm > x_norm]`.  Does torch have those concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a boolean mask for your condition:

```
import torch

x = torch.rand(20, 30, 40, 50)
y = torch.rand(20, 30, 40, 50)

B, C, H, W = x.size()
z = torch.zeros_like(x)

x_norm = torch.norm(x, dim=(2, 3))
y_norm = torch.norm(y, dim=(2, 3))

condition = x_norm >= y_norm  # Create a boolean tensor indicating the condition

# Use the condition to assign values to z without loops
z[condition] = x[condition]
z[~condition] = y[~condition]
```

Though the question does not clarify that, I am assuming that `x` and `y` have the same shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html) to construct the desired tensor based on a condition mask of the same shape as `z`:

```
>>> mask = x.norm(dim=(2,3), keepdim=True) > y.norm(dim=(2,3), keepdim=True) 
>>> torch.where(mask.repeat(1,1,H,W), x, y)
```